Existence of injective compact operator for separable Banach space
I want to show that if $X$ is a separable Banach space, then there exist a Banach space $Y$ and an injective compact operator from $X$ to $Y$. I know that it's true, since I have seen this fact multiple times (e.g. here), but I don't know how to prove it.
I tried to find single space $Y$ for every $X$ expliciliy, but haven't succeed. Also as a main example of $X$ I considered $C[0,1]$, and I wasn't able to find space $Y$ and compact injective map even for this particular case. I also tried to consider embedding of $X$ into it's topological dual space $X'$, but that also didn't work.

For $X=C[0,1]$, you can take the map that sends $u$ to the solution of the bvp $-v''=u$, $v(0)=v(1)=0$, and $Y=X$.

And any separable $X$ embeds into $C(0,1)$ isometrically

For future reference, the article Goldberg and A.H. Kruse, The Existence of Compact Linear Maps Between Banach Spaces. Proc. A.M.S. 13 (1962), 808-811 (mentioned in a MO post linked to the one you gave as an example) gives criteria for the existence of given classes of compact operators, including compact injective ones but also compact operators with dense range.

Every separable Banach space embeds isometrically into $\ell^\infty$. The multiplication operator $T \colon \ell^\infty \to c_0$ given by $$(x_n)\mapsto \left (\frac{x_n}{n}\right)$$
is compact and injective.
